# Select and delete rows in r

Tags: r, comparison

I have a data frame `df`

```
pw pl
30 40
32 39
29 38
32 41
31 39
28 42
31 42
```

and a subset of `df` called `subset`

```
pw pl
29 38
32 41
31 39
```

and I want to delete all rows in `df` that exists in `subset` so that `df` looks like this

```
pw pl
30 40
32 39
28 42
31 42
```

How do I do that?

Comment: You should at least provide some reproducible data.

Comment: Check out e.g. `setdiff`.

Comment: I edited the text to include reproducible data so the question is much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `subset` is truly a subset of `df` and no additional rows have been omitted or added to `df`, filter using row names will work.

```
xy <- data.frame(sub = rep(letters[1:3], 9), val = runif(9))
xy.sub <- xy[xy$sub %in% "b", ]

xy[!rownames(xy) %in% rownames(xy.sub), ]
```

To match multiple columns, you can do

```
xy[!(xy$val %in% xy.sub$val & xy$sub %in% xy.sub$sub), ] #notice the braces
```